# PowerShell script to add network printer and map network drive when offline

Tags: windows-10, powershell, network-printer

Is it possible to add network printer and map a network drive "on hold" when you are offline?

E.g. running commands like these when you are offline but when you connect to network YYY printer installation will complete and share `\\server\my media` is mapped as drive x.

```
net use x: "\\server\my media" /persistent:yes

rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n\\COMPUTER\PRINTER
```

Answer (score 0):

No. These commands establish *connections* to the desired resource. To do that, the command must have access to the resource in order to establish the initial connection. This cannot be done if the resource isn't accessible.

Your alternate approach would be to trigger these commands when you know the resource will be accessible. Here are a few ideas for how to do that:

- Schedule a script that runs at computer startup or user logon. Have it handle failures silently if the target resource doesn't exist.
- If your device is an Active Directory domain member, use Group Policy Preferences to establish these connections. These properly handle situations where the device isn't accessible.

Comment: Maybe you could install printer and map a drive in one computer and then copy those settins from registry and apply those settings for other computers?

Comment: Why go to all that trouble when running a script at the correct time would come with the guarantee of actually working?